# how to detect a human when crossing a line in video with matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

**I do detect a human moving in the train station.but i want to when the person to near red line(warning line) creat an alarm or creat a red box.i want to do in matlab.**

Comment: this is way to broad of a question you need to post code

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) in the Computer Vision System Toolbox showing how to track moving objects with a stationary camera. You can easily modify it to create an alarm if the person is near a given line.

Comment: I have used example in computer vision system.but my problem is creat alarm.help me about write its matlab code.

Comment: I want to complete my project whit write code about cross a line.help me please

Comment: how to do?i don't modify the program.help me to creat alarm